# Vertical Align Middle asp.net controls

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have looked at all the examples posted and none seem to work for me.

I have the following on an asp .net page

```aspx
<div style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
    <div style="float: left;height: 24px">
        <asp:Image ID="PFDExpandColapseImg" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="PFDOrgPayDateStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;height: 24px">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDAuthorizePending" OnClick="PFDAuthorizePending_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:imagebutton ID="PFDReplicate" OnClick="PFDReplicate_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDSubmit" OnClick="PFDSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDApprove" OnClick="PFDApprove_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDReject" OnClick="PFDReject_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDHistory" OnClick="PFDHistory_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDDelete" OnClick="PFDDelete_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDEdit" OnClick="PFDEdit_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDViewExceptions" OnClick="PFDViewExceptions_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="PFDEditEmployee" OnClick="PFDEditEmployee_Click" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the the PFDExpandColapseImg and the PFDOrgPayDateStatus to be vertically aligned middle.

If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested the following to me and it works

```
<div style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
    <div style="float: left;display:flex;align-items:center;height: 24px">
        <asp:Image ID="PFDExpandColapseImg" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="PFDOrgPayDateStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;height: 24px">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDAuthorizePending" OnClick="PFDAuthorizePending_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:imagebutton ID="PFDReplicate" OnClick="PFDReplicate_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDSubmit" OnClick="PFDSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDApprove" OnClick="PFDApprove_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDReject" OnClick="PFDReject_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDHistory" OnClick="PFDHistory_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDDelete" OnClick="PFDDelete_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDEdit" OnClick="PFDEdit_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="PFDViewExceptions" OnClick="PFDViewExceptions_Click" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="PFDEditEmployee" OnClick="PFDEditEmployee_Click" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```